# Introductory material on machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, documentation, guidelines

Does Mathematica have a handbook or other introductory material on machine learning? Or are there any books on analyzing machine learning with Mathematica?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Mathematica-Wolfram-Data-Science/dp/1484265939 , https://www.wolfram-media.com/products/introduction-to-machine-learning.html ,  and [*ML with MMA*](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-with-mathematica-4c0da30b3073)  , and the [*Wolfram courses*](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/wl105/) and Wolfram notes/material - they have some nice notes.

Comment: I also found this quite useful for a high level overview: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2017/05/machine-learning-for-middle-schoolers/

Answer (score 5):

The book, Introduction to Machine Learning, is free to read online. It has detailed examples and is an excellent introduction to the field using Wolfram language. https://www.wolfram.com/language/introduction-machine-learning/

Comment: A WC thread where the author (Etienne Bernard) introduces his book: "[\[BOOK\] Introduction to machine learning](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2469295)."